# Complex SQL relation

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I want to design a MySQL database with the following tables:

- `people`, with one record per person, and an `id` index
- `shirts`, with an `id` index, each shirt belonging to a person, given by a `people_id` field, on which we can set a relation to the first table
- `pants`, with an `id` index, each shirt belonging to a person, given by a `people_id` field, on which we can set a relation to the first table

Then, in some other table, each record refers to a fully clothed person, given its `people_id`, `shirt_id`, and `pants_id`. `people_id` is not strictly necessary, as we can find it by looking for the owner of the clothes.

But, for each record, the owner of `shirt_id` and `pants_id` must be the same, we do not want anybody to borrow clothes.

Can we enforce this relation with a complex relation syntax? Or is there a better structure?

Thanks!

Comment: can a person have more than one shirt? or pants?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a person can own multiple clothes (more than one shirt, more than one pair of pants), then what you are describing really isn't a complex relationship, but simply a one to many relationship. You create these by using the primary key of one table (the person table) as a foreign key in the other tables.

```
CREATE TABLE people (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  name varchar(25)
);

CREATE TABLE shirts (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  people_id integer,
  foreign key (people_id) references people(id)
);

CREATE TABLE pants (
  id integer primary key auto_increment,
  people_id integer,
  foreign key (people_id) references people(id)
);
```

With this structure, any row in the `shirts` or `pants` table can belong to only ONE row in the `people` table, but any row in the `people` table may have MANY corresponding entries in the `shirts` or `pants` table.

Given a pair of pants with id '5', you could find their owner with the following query:

```
SELECT people.*
  FROM people 
    INNER JOIN pants
      ON pants.people_id = people.id
  WHERE pants.id = 5;
```

And likewise if you wanted to find all clothes belonging to the person with id 7, you could do:

```
SELECT pants.*, shirts.*
  FROM people
    LEFT JOIN pants
      ON pants.people_id = people.id
    LEFT JOIN shirts
      ON shirts.people_id = people.id
  WHERE people.id = 7;
```

**edit** We use LEFT JOIN here as pointed out below, because we want it to return values even if the person doesn't have pants, or shirts, or either.

If on the other hand, everyone could have only one shirt and one pair of pants, and you still wanted to maintain them in their own tables, you could keep the above table structure and enforce a `UNIQUE` constraint on people_id in both `pants` and `shirts` table.

Comment: Perhaps a `left outer join` may be better on your last `select` sample.

Answer (score 0):

If specific `pants_id` must belong only to one person and so does the `shirt_id` I think that creating two `UNIQUE` indexes: first on `pants_id` alone and second one only on `shirt_id` should give you the needed result (this will ensure that within the table, there could only be one record containing each of the the specific id's).

Hope it helps.